# Drawing function messes up, when creating connection between server and client

Tags: java

I'm working with a a TCPClient class, and a TCPServer class. I've created a drawing program in my TCPClient, and then sending point(drawing) information to the server, and vice-versa, to make all clients running on the server work on the "same" canvas.

TCPServer:

```
public class TCPServer {

    private static final int serverPort = 9000;

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

        ArrayList<Point> completeDrawing = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Point> receivedList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());


            ObjectOutputStream outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            receivedList.addAll((ArrayList<Point>) inFromClient.readObject());
            completeDrawing.addAll(receivedList);
            receivedList.clear();

            outToClient.writeObject(completeDrawing);

            connectionSocket.close();
        }

    }
}
```

TCPClient:

```
public class TCPClient extends JPanel {

    public static ArrayList<Point> location = new ArrayList<>();

    private JTextArea consoleOutput = new JTextArea(1,20);

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
        consoleOutput.setEditable(false);
    }

    public TCPClient() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                synchronized (location) {
                location.add(e.getPoint());
                location.notify();
                }
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                synchronized (location) {
                location.add(e.getPoint());
                location.notify();
                repaint();
                }
            }
        });

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        synchronized (location) {
            if(location.isEmpty()){
                return;
            }

            Point p = location.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < location.size(); i++) {
                Point q = location.get(i);
                g.drawLine(p.x, p.y, q.x, q.y);
                p = q;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])  throws Exception {

        InetAddress SERVERIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing with friends");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TCPClient(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JTextArea IPadress = new JTextArea(1,20);
        IPadress.setEditable(false);
        IPadress.append("DEVICE IP: " + SERVERIP.getHostAddress());
        frame.add(IPadress, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        while(true) {
            synchronized (location) {
                Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);

                ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                outToServer.writeObject(location);

                outToServer.flush();
                location.wait();

                location.addAll((ArrayList<Point>) inFromServer.readObject());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With these classes, my drawing function messes up. It start lagging and stuttering hard, while the drawing only works from one point:
[image]

However, if I comment out my server to client stream, it works just fine (only in one client window of course):
[image]

I have a suspesion the issue is related to the client being overflowed by data, but besides that I do not know how to work around this issue.

Comment: what exactly you commented out?

Comment: @IvanZelenskyy //outToClient.writeObject(completeDrawing);

Comment: I have copied your code and I have it working with no latency. But what is the server suppose to do so that I can check if it's working correctly?

Comment: @WONDERGG, so you just remove server response? in this case in means only that your problem not in client. However it was known from pictures already :)

Comment: Right now the server is just sending back the points that the client sent to it. So when the client draws the points sent from the server, it's just retracing the line that was already drawn.

Comment: I just copied code to IDE runned and readed it again. So, thats what happens here: deadlock!
Also I'm not sure that synchronize-blocks and wait-notify are good idea in 2016

Answer (score 0):

There are too many data on client, because data in 'drawing' arrayLists (on both sides) have a lot duplications. Rewrite code to add only new points to 'location' and 'completeDrawing' lists like:

```
ArrayList<Point> serverPoints = (ArrayList<Point>)inFromServer.readObject();
for(Point p : serverPoints){
  if(!location.contains(p)) location.add(p);
}
```